# Get count of children based on their property via Projection

Tags: java, spring-boot, spring-data-jpa, projection

In my project I have a parent and a child entity. The child has a property 'isDeleted' which is used to include or exclude that record from the total count. A projection is written to get parent and a method is declared with `@Value("#{target.getChildren().size()}")` to get the children count. How do I exclude the children with `isDeleted==1` in the SpEL syntax?
0 denotes 'active' and 1 denotes 'deleted'.

**Parent**

```java
@Entity
public class Parent {
   long id;
   Set<Child> children;

   public Set<Child> getChildren();
}
```

**Child**

```java
public class Child {
   int isDeleted;

   public int getIsDeleted();
}
```

**Projection**

```java
public interface ParentProjection {
    Long getId();
    @Value("#{target.getChildren().size()}")
    int getChildrenCount();
}
```

Comment: One option may be to use a class based projection with a method to return the calculated value. https://docs.spring.io/spring-data/jpa/docs/current/reference/html/#projections.dtos

Answer (score 0, accepted):

in XML based SpEL we can filter list like following:

```
<property name="failedStudents" value="#{studentList.?[marks lt 40]}" />
```

you can try making such expression for your children class
eg: @Value("#{target.getChildren().?[isDeleted eq 1].size()}")